# How to search a file opened in TUI mode of GDB

Tags: debugging, gdb, gnu, tui

I have a file that is several thousand lines long opened in TUI mode of gdb. I would like to search the file for a variable, is that possible? Because the file is long, I am really trying to avoid hunting for the word manually.

Answer (score 1):

There are no TUI specific search commands defined in manual. And gdb is debugger, not code navigation tool (use ctags/cscope/lxr/source navigator; or use [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B) with debugger and with code navigator).

Try to use gdb (non-TUI) command, but it will work only for one next location (I see no "next search" here):

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Search.html#Search

> There are two commands for searching through the current source file for a regular expression.
>
> ```
> forward-search regexp
> search regexp
> ```
>
> The command ‘`forward-search regexp`’ checks each line, starting with the one following the last line listed, for a match for `regexp`. It lists the line that is found. You can use the synonym ‘`search regexp`’ or abbreviate the command name as `fo`.
>
> ```
> reverse-search regexp
> ```
>
> The command ‘`reverse-search regexp`’ checks each line, starting with the one before the last line listed and going backward, for a match for `regexp`. It lists the line that is found. You can abbreviate this command as `rev`.

You can also use `list` commands to change lines displayed in TUI source window - https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/List.html#List